# Access the api inside the docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

I am running a node application in docker container in `host` network, and I exposed the port 53007 using `EXPOSE 53007` in Dockerfile.

I have verified the logs of the container, the application is listening at port 53007
`"server listening on http://127.0.0.1:53007"`
But I am unable to hit the API in postman.

Please suggest where I am doing wrong

Comment: Exposing ports only opens them up for other containers in the same network. You need to map them to a host port if you want to access those ports from outside the container or its network

Comment: @Jcl EXPOSE does nothing except act as documentation. OP runs with the network=host option, so mapping the port also does nothing.

Comment: @HansKilian How to access the host network docker container ? Please suggest

Comment: @HansKilian you are right, I missed the `host` mode part.

Comment: @Vishnupriya try making the application listen on `0.0.0.0` (or on all interfaces, however it's done on yourapplication) instead of on `127.0.0.1`, which would be only listening on the loopback interface inside the container

Comment: @Jcl How to make application listen on ```0.0.0.0``` ?

Comment: @Vishnupriya with the given info, I have no clue, it would depend on the application itself. Being node.js, I'd suspect express and then you'd go `const app = express(); app.listen(53007, '0.0.0.0');`, but your mileage may vary

Comment: I changed, but still not accessible